# Wildcard for PyGTK States

Tags: python, pygtk, state

How do I combine:

```
button.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse("Green"))
button.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_ACTIVE, gtk.gdk.color_parse("Green"))
button.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_SELECTED, gtk.gdk.color_parse("Green"))
```

etc.

Into a one-liner wildcard covering all of the possible states ([See Doc](http://tinyurl.com/y99jzfp))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do that. You can still do it with fewer lines though:

```
states = [gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.STATE_ACTIVE, gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT,
          gtk.STATE_SELECTED, gtk.STATE_INSENSITIVE]

for state in states:
    button.modify_bg(state, gtk.gdk.color_parse("Green"))
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Maybe this comes in handy: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq04.006.htp

Comment: When I use "or", it only respects the last item 
ie. gtk.STATE_ACTIVE